# ksh conditional execution of timeout

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

On some systems, certain commands like `df` and `prtdiag` (Sun only) can hang indefinitely due to various causes. I'm trying to harden my `ksh` scripts so that should they encounter a hang on these, they would fail rather than stall indefinitely. To this end, I'm planning on using the `timeout` command, but it isn't universally available on 100% of our footprint, so I must conditionally use `timeout` *only if it exists*, and the bare command if it doesn't. I would like to find a **compact** one-liner for this as I'll need to plug this into numerous existing command chains with minimal increase of complexity.

For most commands, this is simple. But `timeout` *returns a non-zero status code when it times out* (124, 143 or 271), not just when it fails to run because it doesn't exist (1 or 127). Therefore, the simple `||` operator cannot differentiate between "no such command" and "the operation timed out". As a result, this won't work:

```
(timeout 5 df || df) # will execute bare df if there is no timeout *or* if the first df times out, thus hanging
```

Another option that tests for the timeout command without trying execute it also doesn't work for the same reason. The timeout itself on a time-out condition will look to `||` the same as if the timeout command doesn't exist:

```
(command -v timeout >/dev/null && timeout 5 df || df) # same result
```

I need a compact *if-then-else* for return codes where the return code of the last piece (*else*) is driven solely by the first piece (*if*) and not influenced by the middle one (*then*). If the `timeout` command exists, use it, otherwise, execute the bare command. I do *not* want a time-out condition to result in executing the bare command.

Here's one way that works correctly, by testing twice:

```
(command -v timeout >/dev/null || df; command -v timeout >/dev/null && timeout 5 df)
```

But this doesn't feel very elegant; I'm having to repeat the `command -v timeout >/dev/null` twice. Another option that works with only one test:

```
(command -v timeout >/dev/null; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then timeout 5 df; else df; fi)
```

But the explicit *if-then-else-fi* with the semi-colons and such feels heavy-handed and not as compact as it should be.

Any suggestions for a cleaner, more compact way of doing this? It would need to work in as old as `ksh88` on AIX, Sun, HP-UX and Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `A && B || C` executes C if A **or** B fails. You need to use `if` to separate B and C properly.

Sounds like you'll want to create a function, and likely in a library file: if this is in file `my_timeout.ksh`

```
timeout() {
  if command -v timeout >/dev/null; then
    command timeout "$@"
    # possibly capture $? and add a case statement 
    # if you need to do special things upon actual timeout
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}
```

Then in your scripts the minimal change is:

```
. my_timeout.ksh
timeout df --with args
```

The ksh `.` will look in the PATH for files to source (at least in ksh93, not 100% sure about ksh88). Otherwise, source it by absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a directory `timeout`, and :

- put that in the $PATH, somewhere at the start (before `/bin/` and `/usr/bin`)
- create scripts in that directory like (for example)  `df`:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout 5 /usr/bin/df "$@"
```

(obviously only for the commands you want to have a timeout)